# How to access data sent by user using controller on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

I have a problem saving data sent by a user and using it in my view file, and I can't find a solution in other topics.

This is my code to select a date via a form:

```
<%= select( 'resource', 'field', @benchmark.compositions.find(:all).collect {|u| [u.date_composition] }, :prompt => 'Selected date') %>
```

This is my controller to get this selection:

```
 def sample_method
  @resource_field = params[:resource][:field]
end
```

And this is my line in the routes.rb file:

```
match 'benchmark/sample_method/:resource/:field', :controller => 'benchmarks', :action => 'sample_method'
```

Now I'd like to use the selected value in my view, so I put:

```
<% @resource_field = @benchmark.find(params[:resource][:field]) %>
```

But it says

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[ ]' for nil:NilClass)
```

How can I use my selected value please ?

Answer (score 0):

[**Params**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters)

The problem is you're trying to access the `params` hash in your view

This won't work, as the `params` are [HTTP values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) sent from a request to your site - only being available on a per-request basis. As your view is essentially another request (kind of like a redirect), the `params` are not available in there

When you receive the error:

> undefined method `[ ]' for nil:NilClass

This basically says that your calling of `[]` on the `params` variable is not possible, as this object is `nil` (not populated with data)

--

**Variables**

What you'll have to do is set your data in your controller, as per the [MVC programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (you should *never* have to use `ActiveRecord` methods in your views btw):

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
   def action
       @resource_field = @benchmark.find params[:resource][:field]
   end
end
```

This should make this data available in your view, whilst using the `params` which have just been passed to Rails

Comment: Ok, thanks, I needed this. But I still have the same error because I think that my select function and my sample_method are not linked somehow. When I select a date, it is not stored in my controller. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: In your correction, the benchmark has to have resource and field among is attributes or am I completely mistaking ? Thanks