# How to access data from Select function on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

I really think I am missing something here. I just want to save a date (from function Select), and use it in my view.

This is my code to select a date:

```
<%= select( 'resource', 'field', @benchmark.compositions.find(:all).collect {|u| [u.date_composition] }, :prompt => 'Selected date') %>
```

And this is my controller to get this selection:

```
 def method
   @resource_field = @benchmark.find params[:resource][:field]
 end
```

Now I want to "print" the selected value in my view:

```
 <% method %>
```

But it says that:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)
```

What should I do ?

**EDIT**

My view is simple:

```
<table id='nam' style='border-radius:2px;box-shadow:2px 2px 2px 2px #9B0057;width:100%'>
<thead> 
  <tr>
    <th>Name of the Benchmark</th>  
  </tr>
</thead>


<h3> Please choose your date </h3>

<<%= select( 'resource', 'field', @benchmark.compositions.find(:all).collect {|u| [u.date_composition] }, :prompt => 'Selected date') %>


<% @benchmark.composition.each do |composition| %>

  <tr>
    <td><%= Benchmark.find(composition.benchmark_id).name%></td>
  </tr>

<% end %>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access data sent by user using controller on Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548698/how-to-access-data-sent-by-user-using-controller-on-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: yes but more precise question, i still can't solve this problem

Comment: The error message is pointing to an issue with the `params` hash. I suspect it is `nil` when you're rendering your template. Can you show more of your controller and your view?

Comment: Here is my complete view. My controller is completely normal, the only thing I added is the method above. Tell me if you need anymore details